# how connect to echonest from enyo

Tags: web-services, enyo

I am new to Enyo and web services. I am looking to build a web page with [Enyo](http://www.enyojs.com)  that will require use of Echonest. Can anyone help me understand how to connect to the Echonest service from inside Enyo and whether to use SOAP, REST, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about the Echo Nest found here: http://the.echonest.com ?

Briefly glancing at their API, you may not have to use SOAP or REST since everything is accessible with simple GET requests through the Web service.  It looks like the hardest part of using their API will be generating OAuth signatures for authenticated requests.

As far as the enyo.WebService, http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.WebService, goes, you should be able to include the kind, set the URL and call the .send() method on it.  Then you response handler would get the data back (I recommend json) so you can do what you will with it.

Another option would be to use enyo.Ajax, http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.Ajax, directly.  enyo.WebService wraps that and provides a familiar (to Enyo 1 developers) way to use it.